# Is there a microsoft graph api that allows me to revoke permissions that personal user has given to my application?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-appservice, microsoft-identity-platform

So, user has been using my app for some time, I have access and refresh tokens, and user wants to stop using my app. I need an api that allows me to revoke all permissions that user has given me and delete the app from user’s account.
I have looked into

```
DELETE /oAuth2PermissionGrants/{id}
POST /me/invalidateAllRefreshTokens
POST /me/revokeSignInSessions
```

but none of these work for personal accounts.

Additionally, they require higher permission levels that my app does not need so I don’t think that asking user for User.ReadWrite.All permission just so I can revoke token afterwards is a way to go anyways, since that permission allows me to do much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the mentioned endpoints you mentioned  are not supported for personal Microsoft accounts.

[image]

I have following app roles assigned to the user for the application In azure ad:

**Get:**  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/xxx4/appRoleAssignedTo`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('30d71xxxx4')/appRoleAssignedTo",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "9nqdteP....."
        },
        {
            "id": "jBFaxxx",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "appRoleId": "ba1xxx8b",
            "createdDateTime": "2023-03-30T06:45:25.5679629Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "newuser",
            "principalId": "0e5a118cx9",x
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "kavyarepo",
            "resourceId": "30d718xxx4"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

These roles can be removed using

---

**DELETE** **`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/xx/appRoleAssignedTo/<giveaboveId>`**

---

[assign-user-or-group-access-portal | microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal?pivots=ms-graph)

The user (newuser) has `User.Read.All` Oauth2 permissions /delegated permissions which needs to be revoked .

[image]

[image]

One of the following application and delegated permissions are required to revoke the user permissions:

```
`DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`,`Application.Read.All`
```

As a user with above permission / admin , I could delete the Oauth2permissions to the user :

[image]

[image]

Even after this deletion ,when a delegated permission grant is deleted, the access  is revoked but the access tokens will continue to be valid for their lifetime, but new access tokens will not be granted.

Then you can use **`revokeSignInSessions`** which invalidates all the refresh tokens issued to applications for a user

---

POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/revokeSignInSessions`

---

see:[Delete oAuth2PermissionGrant | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
[image: personal acc not supp]

> Users with personal microsoft account need to navigate to "Apps and
> websites".
>
> You need to ask them to find your app in the list to click "Remove"
> next to each permission to revoke it and then to "Remove these
> permissions" remove app in their account.

References:
[Grant or revoke API permissions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-grant-via-msgraph?tabs=http&pivots=grant-delegated-permissions)